# Getting 'Error saving the document...due to insufficient user rights.'

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount

Have been getting the referenced error when trying to save documents to a partition shared by both Windows and Ubuntu, formatted as NTFS.

I haven't changed anything I'm aware of to cause this.  I'm guessing some setting got changed, but I'm not seeing anything odd in my fstab or .bascrc file.  Any ideas for attempting to debug.

Comment: Run `mount` to see if the filesystem is mounted read only.  What are the user/group owners of the drive?  Have you tried running `chkdsk` in Windows?

Comment: Interesting, looks like it's mounted read-only if errors are encountered.  This is easy enough to fix, but any thoughts on how to debug why there are errors mounting at startup?      `/media/Share ntfs user,errors=remount-ro,auto,exec,rw`

Comment: Fast Startup enabled in Windows (8 or newer) would do that.

Comment: So, disabling Fast Startup would potentially 'fix' it then?

Comment: That doesn't look like output from the mount command.  Where is that info from?  If it's accurate, the `rw` at the end indicates read-write.  I would check group/ownership permissions next.  Run `ls -la` in a folder you're trying to use.

Comment: @xiota, no it's the fstab entry for the drive in question.  correct, it's set up to be read-write, but I question whether it's being mounted as ro due to an error during startup.

Comment: `ls -la` output sample looks like this:    `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 May 26 23:42  .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Jun 15 21:56  ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12288 May  3 15:13 '1 Pictures'
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 May  3 15:13 '2 Jobs'
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 May  3 15:13 '3 Bills'
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8192 Jun 20 23:08 '4 Programming'

`

Comment: Run the `mount` command without any arguments.  It will tell you if the drive is mounted `ro` or `rw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, the issue is caused because your ntfs volume is not "clean", i.e., has not been properly closed. This is, among other possibilities, the case if Windows is set to shut down and start fast. For this reason, you should always *fully* close down Windows if you intent to use the same ntfs partition with another operating system such as Ubuntu.

Ubuntu by default will not mount an unclean ntfs volume. As you specified `errors=remount-ro` in your fstab file, the volume will also be mounted when an error occurs, however as a read-only volume.

Resolution:

- Boot into Windows, have the ntfs volume checked by the Windows disk checking tools.
- Turn "Faststart" off in Windows. Then, Windows will always fully close the volume when shutting down, so it is left in a "clean" state for Ubuntu to use it.
- Always shut down Windows completely (i.e., no hibernate or sleep state).

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you.